# Prevent serialization of standard properties

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xna, xna-4.0

I apply serialization to an instance of class 'Rectangle' in C#/XNA. It works, but it does serialize the property 'Location' of the rectangle. Since this is a default class i cannot use the option [XmlIgnore] to exclude this property.
How do I exclude it?

Let me clarify: This is not about the 'Rectangle' class specificly. Is there a way to tell standard .NET classes/objects, that hey should not serialize a certain property. 
If I create a custom class, I can use [XmlIgnore] IN the class declaration. But in case of a .NET class I cannot edit the class declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `ISerializable` interface to control exactly what you want to serialize.  The details are all here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx

In the `GetObjectData` function, only save the necessary parts of `Rectangle` you want.